# I cannot understand "The token has not been used for six months." in Google OAuth 2 Authentication

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, google-authentication

1.I cannot understand the word "The token has not been used for six months." in Google OAuth 2 Authentication".
Why token expire when token has not been used for six month?
Actually Access Token has a life time not over 3600 seconds then It's will expired.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=pt-PT

2.There is currently a 25-token limit per Google user account.
That means Google can access only 25 peoples in one Application or One Account can access only 25 Application.

Answer (score 0):

1. What they are saying is that Google's Authentication token lifetime is six months. I'm not sure why you think that it would be 3600 seconds. I've only quickly skimmed the [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) specification but I can't find anything that enforces a limit of 3600 seconds. There are examples of it being used but it is not required.
2. For each Google user account only 25 tokens will be issued. So yes essentially you would only be able to get access tokens for 25 applications for that one user account.